# How many levels/stages are in Sonic 4 Episode 1?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog-4-episode-1

The title says it all. I grabbed the one-level demo yesterday on XBox Live and thought it was fun, but before I plunk down 1200 points for it, I'm wondering how many levels are in it.

I know there are only three zones -- so the question becomes, how many levels to a zone? (I believe traditionally there were 3? If they kept that pattern, that would make this a 9-level game, only.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, there are 3 act + 1 boss battle per zone, 4 main zones, and one hidden zone. So I would assume there are **20 levels** in total.

> Episode 1 has four main zones; Splash Hill, Casino Street, Lost Labyrinth, and Mad Gear, inspired by classic zones from Sonic 1 and Sonic 2. Each zone contains three acts followed by a boss battle, which are similar to boss battles from older Sonic games, but with variations added. Levels can either be accessed in any order via a world map, or played continuously one after the other. Once all zones are cleared, players can access the final zone, E.G.G. Station.